# Problem with Diffuse Lighting

Tags: shaders, directx, hlsl, lighting

So I am currently implementing Diffuse & Ambient Lighting based off this tutorial:
https://www.braynzarsoft.net/viewtutorial/q16390-simple-lighting

I think I have implemented everything correctly, so the Ambient & Diffuse Light should work correctly but I just get Ambient Light. Can someone help me fix this? Here is my code.

[image]

**HEADER.H**

```
#pragma once

#define SCREEN_WIDTH 800
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT 600

// include the basic windows header files and the Direct3D header files
#include <windows.h>
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d3dx11.h>
#include <d3dx10.h>
#include <DirectXMath.h>

using namespace DirectX;

// include the Direct3D Library file
#pragma comment (lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx11.lib")
#pragma comment (lib, "d3dx10.lib")

// global declarations
IDXGISwapChain *swapchain;             // the pointer to the swap chain interface
ID3D11Device *dev;                     // the pointer to our Direct3D device interface
ID3D11DeviceContext *devcon;           // the pointer to our Direct3D device context
ID3D11RenderTargetView *backbuffer;    // the pointer to our back buffer
ID3D11Buffer* squareIndexBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* squareVertBuffer;
ID3D11VertexShader* VS;
ID3D11PixelShader* PS;
ID3D10Blob* VS_Buffer;
ID3D10Blob* PS_Buffer;
ID3D11InputLayout* vertLayout;
ID3D11Texture2D* pDepthStencil;
ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDSV;
ID3D11Buffer* cbPerObjectBuffer;
ID3D11Buffer* cbPerFrameBuffer;
ID3D11ShaderResourceView* CubesTexture;
ID3D11SamplerState* CubesTexSamplerState;

XMMATRIX WVP;
XMMATRIX World;
XMMATRIX camView;
XMMATRIX camProjection;

XMVECTOR camPosition;
XMVECTOR camTarget;
XMVECTOR camUp;

XMMATRIX cube1World;
XMMATRIX cube2World;

XMMATRIX Rotation;
XMMATRIX Scale;
XMMATRIX Translation;
float rot = 0.01f;
// function prototypes
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd);    // sets up and initializes Direct3D
void RenderFrame(void);     // renders a single frame
void CleanD3D(void);        // closes Direct3D and releases memory
void InitScene(void);
void UpdateScene(void);

D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] =
{
    { "POSITION", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 0, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "TEXCOORD", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT, 0, 12, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    { "NORMAL", 0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, 20, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 }
};

UINT numElements = ARRAYSIZE(layout);

struct cbPerObject
{
    XMMATRIX WVP;
    XMMATRIX World;
};

struct Vertex
{
    Vertex() {}
    Vertex(float x, float y, float z, float u, float v, float nx, float ny, float nz)
        : pos(x, y, z), texCoord(u, v), normal(nx, ny, nz){}
    XMFLOAT3 pos;
    XMFLOAT2 texCoord;
    XMFLOAT3 normal; 
};

struct Light
{
    Light()
    {
        ZeroMemory(this, sizeof(Light));
    }
    XMFLOAT3 dir;
    float pad;
    XMFLOAT4 ambient;
    XMFLOAT4 diffuse;
};

Light light;

struct cbPerFrame
{
    Light  light;
};

cbPerFrame constbuffPerFrame;
```

**MAIN.CPP**

```
#include "Header.h"

// the WindowProc function prototype
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);


// the entry point for any Windows program
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,
    HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    LPSTR lpCmdLine,
    int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd;
    WNDCLASSEX wc;

    ZeroMemory(&wc, sizeof(WNDCLASSEX));

    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WindowProc;
    wc.hInstance = hInstance;
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"WindowClass";

    RegisterClassEx(&wc);

    RECT wr = { 0, 0, 800, 600 };
    AdjustWindowRect(&wr, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, FALSE);

    hWnd = CreateWindowEx(NULL,
        L"WindowClass",
        L"Eagle Engine (Alpha)",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        SCREEN_WIDTH,
        SCREEN_HEIGHT,
        wr.right - wr.left,
        wr.bottom - wr.top,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL);

    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);

    // set up and initialize Direct3D
    InitD3D(hWnd);

    // enter the main loop:

    MSG msg;

    while (TRUE)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);

            if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
                break;
        }

        RenderFrame();
    }

    // clean up DirectX and COM
    CleanD3D();

    return msg.wParam;
}


// this is the main message handler for the program
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
    {
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    } break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

cbPerObject cbPerObj;

// this function initializes and prepares Direct3D for use
void InitD3D(HWND hWnd)
{
    // create a struct to hold information about the swap chain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scd;

    // clear out the struct for use
    ZeroMemory(&scd, sizeof(DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC));

    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // fill the swap chain description struct
    scd.BufferCount = 2;                                    // one back buffer
    scd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;     // use 32-bit color
    scd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;      // how swap chain is to be used
    scd.OutputWindow = hWnd;                                // the window to be used
    scd.SampleDesc.Count = 8;                               // how many multisamples
    scd.SampleDesc.Quality = 1;
    scd.Windowed = TRUE;
    scd.Flags = DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_FLAG_ALLOW_MODE_SWITCH;     // allow full-screen switching// windowed/full-screen mode
                                                            // create a device, device context and swap chain using the information in the scd struct

    hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scd,
        &swapchain,
        &dev,
        NULL,
        &devcon);

    // get the address of the back buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *pBackBuffer;
    swapchain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&pBackBuffer);

    // use the back buffer address to create the render target
    dev->CreateRenderTargetView(pBackBuffer, NULL, &backbuffer);
    pBackBuffer->Release();

    // set the render target as the back buffer
    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, NULL);

    ID3D11Texture2D* pDepthStencil = NULL;
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC descDepth;
    descDepth.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    descDepth.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    descDepth.MipLevels = 1;
    descDepth.ArraySize = 1;
    descDepth.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Count = scd.SampleDesc.Count;
    descDepth.SampleDesc.Quality = scd.SampleDesc.Quality;
    descDepth.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    descDepth.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    descDepth.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    descDepth.MiscFlags = 0;
    hr = dev->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &pDepthStencil);

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC descDSV;
    descDSV.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT_S8X24_UINT;
    descDSV.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    descDSV.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    dev->CreateTexture2D(&descDepth, NULL, &pDepthStencil);

    // Create the depth stencil view
    ID3D11DepthStencilView* pDSV;
    hr = dev->CreateDepthStencilView(pDepthStencil, // Depth stencil texture
        &descDSV, // Depth stencil desc
        &pDSV);  // [out] Depth stencil view

    devcon->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &backbuffer, pDSV);


    // Set the viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport;
    ZeroMemory(&viewport, sizeof(D3D11_VIEWPORT));

    viewport.TopLeftX = 0;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0;
    viewport.Width = SCREEN_WIDTH;
    viewport.Height = SCREEN_HEIGHT;
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;

    devcon->RSSetViewports(1, &viewport);

    //Create the buffer to send to the cbuffer in effect file
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC cbbd;
    ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

    cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerObject);
    cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

    dev->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerObjectBuffer);

    ZeroMemory(&cbbd, sizeof(D3D11_BUFFER_DESC));

    cbbd.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    cbbd.ByteWidth = sizeof(cbPerFrame);
    cbbd.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_CONSTANT_BUFFER;
    cbbd.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    cbbd.MiscFlags = 0;

    dev->CreateBuffer(&cbbd, NULL, &cbPerFrameBuffer);

    //Camera information
    camPosition = XMVectorSet(-5.0f, 3.0f, -5.0f, 0.0f); //Position X,Y,Z
    camTarget = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   //Rotation X,Y,Z
    camUp = XMVectorSet(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

    //Set the View matrix
    camView = XMMatrixLookAtLH(camPosition, camTarget, camUp);

    //Set the Projection matrix
    camProjection = XMMatrixPerspectiveFovLH(0.4f*3.14f, (float)SCREEN_WIDTH/SCREEN_HEIGHT , 1.0f, 1000.0f);

    D3DX11CreateShaderResourceViewFromFile(dev, L"braynzar.jpg", NULL, NULL, &CubesTexture, NULL);

    D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC sampDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&sampDesc, sizeof(sampDesc));
    sampDesc.Filter = D3D11_FILTER_MIN_MAG_MIP_LINEAR;
    sampDesc.AddressU = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.AddressV = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.AddressW = D3D11_TEXTURE_ADDRESS_WRAP;
    sampDesc.ComparisonFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_NEVER;
    sampDesc.MinLOD = 0;
    sampDesc.MaxLOD = D3D11_FLOAT32_MAX;

    dev->CreateSamplerState(&sampDesc, &CubesTexSamplerState);
    InitScene();
    UpdateScene();
}

// this is the function used to render a single frame
void RenderFrame(void)
{
    //Clear our backbuffer
    float bgColor[4] = { (0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) };
    devcon->ClearRenderTargetView(backbuffer, bgColor);

    //Refresh the Depth/Stencil view
    devcon->ClearDepthStencilView(pDSV, D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

    constbuffPerFrame.light = light;
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerFrameBuffer, 0, NULL, &constbuffPerFrame, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerFrameBuffer);

    ///////////////**************new**************////////////////////
    //Set the WVP matrix and send it to the constant buffer in effect file
    WVP = cube1World * camView * camProjection;
    cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0);
    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &CubesTexture);
    devcon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &CubesTexSamplerState);

    //Draw the first cube
    devcon->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);

    WVP = cube2World * camView * camProjection;
    cbPerObj.WVP = XMMatrixTranspose(WVP);
    devcon->UpdateSubresource(cbPerObjectBuffer, 0, NULL, &cbPerObj, 0, 0);
    devcon->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 1, &cbPerObjectBuffer);
    devcon->PSSetShaderResources(0, 1, &CubesTexture);
    devcon->PSSetSamplers(0, 1, &CubesTexSamplerState);

    //Draw the second cube
    devcon->DrawIndexed(36, 0, 0);
    ///////////////**************new**************////////////////////

    //Present the backbuffer to the screen
    swapchain->Present(0, 0);
};


// this is the function that cleans up Direct3D and COM
void CleanD3D(void)
{
    swapchain->SetFullscreenState(FALSE, NULL);    // switch to windowed mode

    // close and release all existing COM objects
    swapchain->Release();
    dev->Release();
    backbuffer->Release();
    devcon->Release();
    squareIndexBuffer->Release();
    squareVertBuffer->Release();
    VS->Release();
    PS->Release();
    VS_Buffer->Release();
    PS_Buffer->Release();
    vertLayout->Release();
    cbPerObjectBuffer->Release();
    cbPerFrameBuffer->Release();
}

void InitScene()
{
    //Compile Shaders from shader file
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "VS", "vs_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &VS_Buffer, 0, 0);
    D3DX11CompileFromFile(L"Effects.fx", 0, 0, "PS", "ps_4_0", 0, 0, 0, &PS_Buffer, 0, 0);

    //Create the Shader Objects
    dev->CreateVertexShader(VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &VS);
    dev->CreatePixelShader(PS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(), PS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), NULL, &PS);

    //Set Vertex and Pixel Shaders
    devcon->VSSetShader(VS, 0, 0);
    devcon->PSSetShader(PS, 0, 0);

    light.dir = XMFLOAT3(0.25f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    light.ambient = XMFLOAT4(0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f);
    light.diffuse = XMFLOAT4(1.0f, 1.0f, 2.0f, 5.0f);

    //Create the vertex buffer
    Vertex v[] =
    {
        // Front Face
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),

        // Back Face
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f),

        // Top Face
        Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f),

        // Bottom Face
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),

        // Left Face
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,-1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),

        // Right Face
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f, -1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,  1.0f,  1.0f),
        Vertex(1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  1.0f),
    };

    DWORD indices[] =
    {
        // Front Face
        0,  1,  2,
        0,  2,  3,

        // Back Face
        4,  5,  6,
        4,  6,  7,

        // Top Face
        8,  9, 10,
        8, 10, 11,

        // Bottom Face
        12, 13, 14,
        12, 14, 15,

        // Left Face
        16, 17, 18,
        16, 18, 19,

        // Right Face
        20, 21, 22,
        20, 22, 23
    };

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC indexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&indexBufferDesc, sizeof(indexBufferDesc));

    indexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    indexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(DWORD) * 12 * 3;
    indexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_INDEX_BUFFER;
    indexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    indexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA iinitData;

    iinitData.pSysMem = indices;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&indexBufferDesc, &iinitData, &squareIndexBuffer);

    devcon->IASetIndexBuffer(squareIndexBuffer, DXGI_FORMAT_R32_UINT, 0);


    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vertexBufferDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferDesc, sizeof(vertexBufferDesc));

    vertexBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    vertexBufferDesc.ByteWidth = sizeof(Vertex) * 24;
    vertexBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vertexBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    vertexBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vertexBufferData;

    ZeroMemory(&vertexBufferData, sizeof(vertexBufferData));
    vertexBufferData.pSysMem = v;
    dev->CreateBuffer(&vertexBufferDesc, &vertexBufferData, &squareVertBuffer);

    //Set the vertex buffer
    UINT stride = sizeof(Vertex);
    UINT offset = 0;
    devcon->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &squareVertBuffer, &stride, &offset);

    //Create the Input Layout
    dev->CreateInputLayout(layout, numElements, VS_Buffer->GetBufferPointer(),
        VS_Buffer->GetBufferSize(), &vertLayout);

    //Set the Input Layout
    devcon->IASetInputLayout(vertLayout);

    //Set Primitive Topology
    devcon->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);
}

void UpdateScene()
{
    //Reset cube1World
    cube1World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    Translation = XMMatrixTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 4.0f);

    //Define cube2's world space matrix
    Scale = XMMatrixScaling(1.3f, 1.3f, 1.3f);

    //Set cube1's world space using the transformations
    cube1World = Translation;

    //Reset cube2World
    cube2World = XMMatrixIdentity();

    //Set cube2's world space matrix
    cube2World = Scale;
}
```

**EFFECTS.FX**

```
struct Light
{
    float3 dir;
    float4 ambient;
    float4 diffuse;
};

cbuffer cbPerFrame
{
    Light light;
};

cbuffer cbPerObject
{
    float4x4 WVP;
    float4x4 World;
};

Texture2D ObjTexture;
SamplerState ObjSamplerState;

struct VS_OUTPUT
{
    float4 Pos : SV_POSITION;
    float2 TexCoord : TEXCOORD;
    float3 normal : NORMAL;
};

VS_OUTPUT VS(float4 inPos : POSITION, float2 inTexCoord : TEXCOORD, float3 normal : NORMAL)
{
    VS_OUTPUT output;

    output.Pos = mul(inPos, WVP);

    output.normal = mul(normal, World);

    output.TexCoord = inTexCoord;

    return output;
}

float4 PS(VS_OUTPUT input) : SV_TARGET
{
    input.normal = normalize(input.normal);

    float4 diffuse = ObjTexture.Sample(ObjSamplerState, input.TexCoord);

    float3 finalColor;

    finalColor = diffuse * light.ambient;
    finalColor += saturate(dot(light.dir, input.normal) * light.diffuse * diffuse);

    return float4(finalColor, diffuse.a);
}
```

Comment: Note that most of these Internet Direct3D 11 tutorials are woefully outdated and make extensive use of the legacy DirectX SDK and the deprecated D3DX11 library (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee663275.aspx). You should look at the various [replacements](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chuckw/2013/08/20/living-without-d3dx/) and consider using the _DirectX Tool Kit_ [tutorials](https://github.com/Microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Getting-Started).

Comment: You're not giving us the layout of your Light or cbPerFrame structs on the C++ side - please update your code to include those.

Comment: @LeComteduMerde-fou I just edited my question to add the header file containing the Light & cbPerFrame structs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So @vtastek spotted that I hadn't set the world matrix for World in my .FX file which meant I had been multiplying my Normals by an Empty matrix.

```
output.normal = mul(normal, World);
```

Basically what solved my problem was setting the World matrix in my main.cpp to

```
cbPerObj.World = XMMatrixTranspose(cube1World);
```

Well spotted vtastek. Man that Diffuse Lighting is looking good ;)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should add lighting info (specular, ambient, diffuse), then multiply with color. Try this:

```
finalColor = diffuse;
finalColor *= saturate(dot(input.normal, -light.dir)) * light.diffuse + light.ambient;
```

Comment: I tried this but I still get the same results. I asked this exact same question over at gamedev.net, I didn't seem to understand what they were trying to say could you explain some of their answers?: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/682496-problem-with-diffuse-lighting/#entry5312295

Comment: I am struggling with learning matrix operations myself. But as I understand, world holds translation, rotate and scale. In a normal case, your translation would be zero, rotation also zero and scale will be 1, makes sense. There is code for that in there but world is empty indeed. Why not try
 
    world = cube1world;